# the code below not working as intended

Tags: c++, c

I have written this piece of code as an exercise. It counts the bits used to store integer in one's system.

The code here worked fine and gives correct output when I define 
**unsigned int x**,
 but when I define just **int x** it does not produce any result at all. 
The program compiles without any error or warnings but does not display anything on the terminal when declaring **x** as just **int**

```
int int_size ()
{
    int x = ~0;
    char bit_count = 0;
    while ( x != 0 )
    {
        x >>= 1;
        bit_count++;
    }
    return bit_count;
}
```

It works fine with the unsigned **int x** declaration. I am just curious to know why it behaves wierdly when using the **signed int** declaration.

F.Y.I - I m using **CODE::BLOCKS** IDE with the **gcc compiler**.

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger? Have you tried to add traces? Just print `x` in the loop to understand what happens!